# Not nested double integral java library

Tags: java, integral

I am looking for a java library that computes a double integral without having to nest them.
I already found a library that allows me to do the following:

```
    Integral of x*x*{integral of y*y} for x between 0 and 1 and for y between x and 5
```

Where i have to solve the inner integral first then i can solve the outer integral. This works fine if

```
    f(x,y) = x^2 * y^2 can be seperated into two functions, g(x) = x^2 and h(y) = y^2.
```

However what i need to integrate is the following:

```
    Integral of e^((x-y)^2) for x between 5 and 10 and y between 3 and 7
```

is there a library that allows me to call something like this

```
    Integrate (e^((x-y)^2), {x,5,10}, {y,3;7})
```

I need this to be a java library not an external tool because the whole code should then best exported as a library and used on an android phone.

Comment: Are you talking about a symbolic algebra solver, or something that gives you numeric answers?  What have you found already?

Comment: I need a numerical answer. I found this:http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Integration.html

Comment: I also tried with mathematica to see if the formula i am trying to integrate can be solved and gives a numerical answer without nesting and it worked.